# How to create another html.tpl.php file for logged in users?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and I want to create another (different) `html.tpl.php` file for logged in users only.

So, I need to check if user is logged in and set other `html.tpl.php` file if a user is logged.

Is this possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement `hook_preprocess_html()` in your theme (or module, both are equally valid) like so:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  // Determine if the user is auth'd
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    // Add a theme hook suggestion.
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__auth';
  }
}
```

Then add a html--auth.tpl.php file to your theme, clear the caches, and you should be good to go.

Comment: works like a charm...thanks a lot...is there way to do the same thing but for specific pages (urls)?

Comment: I think [this](https://drupal.org/node/1189732) is what you're looking for...